# Fail to show transitions effect in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I have a simple test Flutter web app with 3 pages: Home, Transactions, and Settings; default page is Home.  Transition effect only appears when I switch page from (or go back to) Home.  If I switch between these 2 pages, no transition effect applies.

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Row(children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => context.go("/"),
                  child: const Text("Home"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => context.go("/settings"),
                  child: const Text("Go to Settings page"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => context.go("/transactions"),
                  child: const Text("Go to Transactions page"),
                ),
              ]),
              Expanded(
                child: child,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "/",
          pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
              TemplateTransition(HomePage()),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: "transactions",
              pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  return TemplateTransition(TransactionsPage());
              },
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: "tx_details/:id",
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                      TemplateTransition(TransactionDetailsPage(id: state.pathParameters['id'])),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: "settings",
              pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                TemplateTransition(SettingsPage()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

Page TemplateTransition(routePage) {
  switch (globals.TransitionEffect){
    case 1:
      Duration sec = Duration(seconds:2);
      return CustomTransitionPage(
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
            FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
        child: routePage,
        transitionDuration: sec,
        reverseTransitionDuration: sec,
      );
      break;

    default:
      return NoTransitionPage(child: routePage);
      break;
  }
}
```

To separate Transition Effect to a separate class is to allow users to switch between different effects. Now globals.TransitionEffect is set to 1.